# Generics Imbrication

Tags: delphi

I have this 3 classes :

```
TClassA = Class(Tobject);
end;

TClassB = Class(Tobject);
  Child: TClassA;
end;

TClassC = Class(Tobject);
  Child: TClassB;  
end;
```

Now I need to override this hierarchy like this :

```
TMyClassA = Class(TClassA);
end;

TMyClassB = Class(TClassB);
  Child: TMyClassA;
end;

TMyClassC = Class(TClassC);
  Child: TMyClassB;  
end;
```

How can I avoid to write this second hierarchy and use instead generic in the first one? I would like to do something like
`TClassC<B: TClassB, A: TClassA>` but I don't found how to write it

I try something like this but it's didn't work :

```
TClassA = Class(Tobject)
end;

TClassB<A: TClassA> = Class(Tobject)
  Child: A;
end;

TClassC<B: TClassB> = Class(Tobject)
  Child: B;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics are no good solution to this task.

Assuming that you don't want a second `Child` field in your second hierarchy because you already get the one from the base class, you better introduce a property with getter and setter to narrow the type from `TClassA` to `TMyClassA`.

```
TClassA = class
end;

TClassB = class ​
  ​FChild: TClassA;
  ​property Child: TClassA {getter, setter};
​end;
​
​TClassC = class
  ​FChild: TClassB;
  property Child: TClassB {getter, setter};
end;


TMyClassA = class(TClassA)
end;

TMyClassB = class(TClassB)
  property Child: TMyClassA {getter, setter};
end;

TMyClassC = class(TClassC)
  property Child: TMyClassB {getter, setter};
end;
```

Comment: Thanks stefan, yes actually this is how I m doing using hard cast

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't use a Generic class as input to another Generic class.  So you can't use `TClassB` as a Generic parameter for `TClassC`.

But, you can try something more like this instead:

```pascal
TClassA = class(TObject)
end;

TClassB_Base = class(TObject)
end;

TClassB<A: TClassA> = class(TClassB_Base)
  Child: A;
end;

TClassC<B: TClassB_Base> = class(TObject)
  Child: B;
end;
```

```pascal
TMyClassA = class(TClassA)
end;

TMyClassB = class(TClassB<TMyClassA>)
end;

TMyClassC = class(TClassC<TMyClassB>)
end;
```

Comment: thanks remy :) I tend to prefer the solution of stefen and use reintroduce of getter+setter with hard casting but I think it's just matter of taste :)